# Reading XML data from a file in python using Element tree

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I am trying to print data from my xml file but using ElementTree is not helping. Data is being successfully written into the file 'data.xml' but cant be read, console terminated with exit code 0 without displaying any data. The 'data.findall' loop is not even being entered into.

```
import urllib2
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

def main():
    search_url = "http://export.arxiv.org/api/query?search_query=all:social+science&start=0&max_results=10&sortBy=submittedDate&sortOrder=descending"
    file1 = open("data.xml", 'w')
    file1.write(''.join(map(str, urllib2.urlopen(search_url))))
    file1.close()
    print_data()    

def print_data():
    data = ET.parse('data.xml').getroot()
    for child in data.findall('entry'):
        print "Title :" + child.find('title').text + "\n"
        print "hahah"
        print "Summary :" + child.find('summary').text + "\n"
        print "Published On :" + child.find('published').text + "\n"
        for grab in child.find('link'):
            if grab.get('type') == 'application/pdf':
                print "Download Link :" + grab.get('href').text
                link = grab.get('href').text
                get_data = urllib2.urlopen(link)
                file2 = open('paper.pdf', 'w')
                file2.write(get_data.read())
                file2.close()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass namespace to findall along with the tag-name.

Replace this:

```
for child in data.findall('entry'):
```

With this:

```
for child in data.findall('{http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}entry'):
```

where http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom is the value of xmlns attribute of the root element from data.xml

Comment: Thanks, It worked by adding the name space, although I tried to add name space before as well, but not {http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}, which tells me what the problem was. But now I have to add this name space to every tag inside the for loop as well to get job done. Is there some workaround for that.

Comment: Can someone also explain why name space is so important in reading XML data.

Answer (score 0):

> Element.findall() finds only elements with a tag which are direct
>   children of the current element. Element.find() finds the first child
>   with a particular tag, and Element.text accesses the element’s text
>   content. Element.get() accesses the element’s attributes:
>   https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html

So, I try to find:

```
def print_data():
    data = ET.parse('data.xml').getroot()
    for child in data.findall('entry'):
        for entry in child.findall('entry'):
            print entry
```

and this code find all entries, why a lot of entries aren't direct children, i don't now.